# Alternate to SqlTransaction exposing Events - C#?

Tags: c#, events, ado.net, transactions

I want to perform some logging when a SqlTransaction is committed or rolledback. I see that SqlTransaction class does not expose any such events like OnCommit or OnRollback.

damn! SqlTransaction class is sealed, I cant help it out with inheritance.

Now, what must be the reason they have not allowed these events to happen ?

Is there a way to do these events with SqlTransaction or any such alternate of SqlTransaction that provides ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to create a class that implements IDbTransaction, and wraps an internal SqlTransaction. You would then have to say something like:

```
IDbCommand icommand = (IDbCommand)command; // Where command is a SqlCommand.
command.Transaction = itransaction; // Class implementing IDbTransaction and wrapping SqlTransaction.
```

I have *not* tried this and the above must be considered pseudocode. I'm skeptical it will even work, but it's probably worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

Nope. Nothing built-in on SqlTransaction, nor per command ones on SqlCommand.

Best you can do is wrap this up with your own class that provides the notifications.

Comment: just edited my question. SqlTransaction is sealed. cant help it.

Answer (score 0):

We use a wrapper around the SqlTransaction in our systems. I think it's pretty lame, but it works mostly. See below for the full class we use. It's pretty straightforward actually.

Because all our methods now have a transaction parameter of the CpoTransaction type we also added a WrapTransaction static function to make a CpoTransaction out of a regular transaction in case the regular SqlTransaction was already started.

Note that in those cases the transaction is likely committed/rolled back using the regular SqlTransaction and the events will ofc not fire (hence the lameness of having to resort to a solution like this).

```
/// <summary>
/// Provides a wrapper around an SqlTransaction that raises events on commit and rollback
/// </summary>
public partial class CpoTransaction : IDisposable {
    private SqlTransaction mTransaction;
    private bool mHasEnded;
    public event EventHandler Committed, RolledBack;

    /// <summary>
    /// Provides a wrapper around an SqlTransaction that raises events on commit and rollback
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="innerTransaction">The SqlTransaction to wrap</param>
    internal CpoTransaction(SqlTransaction innerTransaction) {
        mTransaction = innerTransaction;
        mHasEnded = false;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Rolls back the transaction from a pending state.
    /// </summary>
    internal void RollBack() {
        if (!mHasEnded) {
            mTransaction.Rollback();
            OnRolledBack(this, new EventArgs());
            mHasEnded = true;
        } else
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Transaction has already ended.");
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Commits the database transaction
    /// </summary>
    internal void Commit() {
        if (!mHasEnded) {
            mTransaction.Commit();
            OnCommitted(this, new EventArgs());
            mHasEnded = true;
        } else
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Transaction has already ended.");
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Add the SqlTransaction and its associated SqlConnection to the SqlCommand
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="command">The command to add the SqlTransaction and SqlConnection to</param>
    internal void SetTransaction(SqlCommand command) {
        if (command == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("command");
        command.Connection = mTransaction.Connection;
        command.Transaction = mTransaction;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets whether or not the transaction has ended
    /// </summary>
    internal bool HasEnded {
        get { return mHasEnded; }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the internal SqlConnection
    /// </summary>
    internal SqlConnection Connection {
        get { return mTransaction.Connection; }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the internal SqlTransaction
    /// </summary>
    public SqlTransaction InnerTransaction {
        get { return mTransaction; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Wraps an existing SqlTransaction into a CpoTransaction. IMPORTANT: See remarks!
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="transaction">The transaction to wrap</param>
    /// <returns>The SqlTransaction wrapped in a CpoTransaction</returns>
    /// <remarks>
    /// Use this method to allow CPO actions to be performed within the context of an already
    /// existing transaction.
    /// Note however that if the SqlTransaction is committed or rolled back without the use of the 
    /// CpoTransaction's Commit/Rollback functions, the events will not fire.
    /// </remarks>
    public static CpoTransaction WrapTransaction(SqlTransaction transaction) {
        return new CpoTransaction(transaction);
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Disposes the SqlTransaction
    /// </summary>
    public void Dispose() {
        mTransaction.Dispose();
        if (!mHasEnded)
            OnRolledBack(this, new EventArgs());
        mHasEnded = true;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Raises the Committed event
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">The sender of the event</param>
    /// <param name="e">An EventArgs object containing event data</param>
    protected void OnCommitted(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        if (Committed != null)
            Committed(sender, e);
        Committed = null;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Raises the RolledBack event
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">The sender of the event</param>
    /// <param name="e">An EventArgs object containing event data</param>
    protected void OnRolledBack(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        if (RolledBack != null)
            RolledBack(sender, e);
        RolledBack = null;
    }
}
```